# Is it possible for a React component to inherit its parent's generic type paramter?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Consider the following code:

```js
type FooBar = 'Foo' | 'Bar'
return (
  <Select<FooBar>>
    <Select.Option value="Foo">Foo</Select.Option>
    <Select.Option value="Bogus">Bogus</Select.Option>
  </Select>
)
```

Here `Select` works largely as `RcSelect` from `rc-select`.  `RcSelect` has a `ValueType` as its first generic parameter, that influences its functions (such as `onSelect`), but it doesn't restrict its `Option`s to the same `ValueType`.

The above code - using `RcSelect` at least - won't fail, but I would like TypeScript to complain about the second `Option`, that its value did not match the type `FooBar`.

I could solve the problem by writing a wrapper `Option` component that takes a generic type parameter as well (e.g. `<Select.Option<FooBar> ...`), but that's not a desirable option, since it requires great programmer care to ensure all options have a generic type parameter *and* the same generic type parameter.  (Plus, TypeScript wouldn't immediately start complaining about all my existing code, so I could go around and fixing it.)

So the question is; is it possible for a React component to inherit the generic type parameter of its or any parent component?

It would also be nice, if it would work for more flexible lists of options, e.g.

```js
  <Select<FooBar>>
    {list.map((item) => <Select.Option value={item.value}>{item.value}</Select.Option>)}
  </Select>
```

Comment: *"...but I would like TypeScript to complain about the second `Option`, that its `value` did not match the type `FooBar`."* There are a few previous questions asking about limiting React children by type. Unfortunately, the answer is that TypeScript can't do that right now. I'll try to find one to point to.

Comment: Thank you so much (even if the answer is no).  I knew I just didn't have the right keyword to search for.  I'll leave this question up, in case someone else - like me - didn't use the right keyword.

Comment:  That's one of the reasons the system uses close-as-duplicate instead of delete-as-duplicate. Each duplicate referring back to the earlier answered question increases the search surface. :-) Happy coding!